# Best open source tool to convert avi type 1 files to rgb

Tags: software-recommendation

I have a capture card that produces DV video in AVI Type 1 container files.
I would like to convert the video to RGB, do some image processing,
and then convert the video back to DV-AVI and optionally code to DVD.

The original video sources are all either films that were telecined
for NTSC broadcast, stored on LaserDisc, or native NTSC broadcast
(i.e. shot with broadcast camera). But I might want to convert DVD data to RGB also.

The image processing functions include image stabilization, dust/scratch
removal, filtering large areas of single color in the broadcast material,
correcting inter-field artifacts, etc.

I assume I will have to write software to do most of the image processing,
but what is the best tool to do the conversion from DV to RGB, and RGB to DV or  DVD?

So far I see ffmpeg, avidemux and transcode as possibilities.

Comment: RGB refers to the pixel format and not to any specific video codec as such. H.264 can contain RGB pixels, as can Qucktime RLE or PNG. There are others as well. All the off-the-shelf VFX software can ingest DV AVIs and do the tasks you want - they convert to RGB internally. If you're going to write the code for the video processing yourself, you can just include a YUV <-> RGB conversion in there.The formulas for available online for BT-601 NTSC colorspace (and others as well).